# Error:Variable might not have been initialised

Tags: java, variables, initialization

I don't know what is wrong with this code and why it is giving the error:

> Variable isPrime might not have been initialized

This is the complete code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class PrimeNumberTest {
    //Program to test for prime numbers

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner prime = new Scanner(System.in);
        int number;
        boolean isPrime;
        System.out.print("Please enter number: ");
        number = prime.nextInt();


        if (number < 2)
            isPrime = false;
        else{
            for (int i = 2; i < number / 2; i++)
                if (number % i == 0){
                isPrime = false;
                break;
                }
            }

        if (isPrime)
            System.out.println("Your number is a prime number");
        else
            System.out.println("Your number is not a prime number");
    }
}
```

Comment: in your case, make `boolean isPrime = true;`

Comment: The issue is that there can be a case where the for loop never executes because the condition is not met. 
If you did the assignment in the else outside of the for loop, the error should go away.

Comment: isPrime has no initiale value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
boolean isPrime = false;
```

Just initialize `isPrime` boolean.